# PCI WiFi module for Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10?

Tags: networking, dual-boot, drivers

I search PCI WiFi module for Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10. I found modules which support Windows 10 but not support Ubuntu, or support Ubuntu but Windows 7(and less).

This module https://www.asus.com/Networking/PCIN10/specifications/ can be work with Windows 10 too? They write `Linux Kernel (Support Ubuntu only)` it means if after year I want to install Debian instead of Ubuntu this WiFi module will be trash?

Maybe somebody knows the cheap and practical solution for Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 bundle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to solve your problem is to use a USB wireless dongle. If you purchase a popular dongle, this will typically have support in both Windows and Ubuntu. Ubuntu may require that you install a driver for it. Edimax and D-Link sell 802.11 b/g/n/ac adapters which should work.

The PCI card that you reference is really old and slow. Look elsewhere if you must have a PCI solution.

Comment: thank you `The fastest way to solve your problem is to use a USB wireless dongle.` Can you recommend something concrete USB model for the good connection speed? I mean for "landmark". My system is the home edition 100mb/s not industrial.

Comment: @Pavel it all depends on your network environment. The latest technology is "ac", and provides the fastest and most reliable connections... but you have to have an "ac" wireless router and network gear to use it properly. I've always had good luck with Edimax dongles... and they make a fast one that works at 1750 speed.

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded the Asus-provided driver. First, the version that they offer was written in 2010 for kernel version 2.4. Ubuntu 18.04 uses kernel version 4.15. The provided driver will never compile on any recent (not end-of-life) Ubuntu version.

However, examining the pci.ids listed in the driver code, it is quite apparent that the device is driven by the driver already included in the 4.15, and many earlier kernels, *rt2800pci*.

Because of this, the device should work without installing anything extra in Ubuntu and any other modern Linux distribution.

Comment: very informative answer about PCIN10. Thank you!